# Why is MySQL COUNT returning double of what I expect when counting joined columns?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a user notification system in wordpress. I have a query that joins rows in the wp_posts table that have a post_status of publish, a post_author of 1 and a post_type of user_notification. There are two rows that meet these requirements. The total_unread column is always 4 and the entire query only returns 1 row. What am I doing wrong? Here is a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e88c5d/4)

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20),
  `post_author` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `post_content` longtext NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'publish',
  `post_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'post'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO wp_posts
(ID, post_author, post_content, post_status, post_type)
VALUES(1, 1, 'John Smith would like to be friends!', 'publish', 'user_notification');
INSERT INTO wp_posts
(ID, post_author, post_content, post_status, post_type)
VALUES(2, 1, 'Sally Miller shared your post!', 'publish', 'user_notification');
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_status, COUNT(unread.post_status) as total_unread 
FROM wp_posts  
 JOIN wp_posts AS unread ON unread.post_author = 1 AND unread.post_status = 'publish' AND unread.post_type = 'user_notification'
WHERE wp_posts.post_author IN (1)  
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'user_notification' 
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Offtopic: You can remove `1=1` from your WHERE clause it's always true and it looks clumsy

Comment: Ah, yeah I'm not sure why Wordpress adds that into their WP_Query function.

Comment: What results do you expect? Because you are using COUNT without GROUP BY what always results in one record.. And you clearly want more records because you are using `LIMIT 0, 5`.. Besides i cant really figure out on why you used a self join on that table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `JOIN` is creating a cross-product of each post with each other post, so you get a count of 4 (2x2). If you had 3 similar rows in the table you would get a count of 9. Try running the query as `SELECT *` instead of your current fields and you will see the 4 rows.

I don't really understand why you are using a `JOIN`? What are you trying to achieve? If all you want to do is count the "unread" posts (indicated by `post_status='publish'`) this query will suffice:

```
SELECT post_author, SUM(IF(post_status='publish',1,0)) as total_unread 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'user_notification' 
GROUP BY post_author
```

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as total_unread 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'user_notification' AND post_status='publish'
GROUP BY post_author
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84b67d/1) added another record which was `unpublished` to see how the results would be and it was still doubling the value.

ALSO When using JOIN your query should be structured more like this :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts t1
JOIN wp_posts t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE...
//attempted this in your fiddle and it actually resolves your issue.
```

Since your JOIN has no such relationship this can all be done with one single query. I kept all your parameters because you might want the statistic for a unique user. You can view the result in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83e9e2/2) where I have added another `post_author`.

Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT post_author, post_status, COUNT(post_author) as total_unread 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'user_notification' 
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = 1
GROUP BY post_author
```